# Oracle APEX: Hide a button with dynamic actions

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm tying to **hide a button when a checkbox is deselected** and **show the button when selected**. But I don't know why isn't it working because I have two date item and they are working fine.

When checkbox not selected
[image]

When checkbox selected
[image]

> http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=17236:555 
>  Workspace:
>   MACWADU_ORACLE 
>  Username: USER
>  Password: 123qweASD

If someone wants to help me, can go to the application page 555 or explain here what I have to do.

Tanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dynamic action tries to hide the button using the DOM Selector "APPLY_CHANGES", but this isn't actually the button's ID (it didn't have an ID at all).

Two changes required (I have made them):

1) Change the Button template to allow button attributes to be added:

```
<button value="#LABEL#" onclick="#LINK#" class="button-gray" type="button"
  #BUTTON_ATTRIBUTES#>
  <span>#LABEL#</span>
</button>
```

2) Change the button itself and set the Button Attributes property to:

```
id="APPLY_CHANGES"
```

Comment: You save my day another time :) Tanks again for your help